# VLC sout custom dynamic file name

Tags: vlc, pi

I have a installed a RPi and hikvision camera with rtsp:// stream in a remote location. The devices are online and working - i can log into the pi via ssh.

I am currently using the below code to ssh in and tell VLC to record 10 seconds of video and then write it to a file

vlc -vvv rtsp:// --sout file:/home/pi/Videos/test.mp4 --run-time=10 vlc://quit

It works - but i'm trying to have VLC name the file dynamically. Ideally, the files should be YYYYMMDD_TIME for example '20191010_0810.mp4'

I can seem to find any information regarding this. Would appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was incredibly hard to find, but this worked and resulted in a file named:

'20191010_211241_video.mp4'

vlc -vvv rtsp:// --sout="#std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=/home/pi/Videos/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_video).mp4}" --run-time=2 vlc://quit